# WordPress: get all meta data when user registers

Tags: wordpress, metadata, user-registration

I have a user registration form in the front end (in the Users admin section as well) with three extra fields (apart from default ones): birthday, country, language. their values are stored in usermeta table.

I have this action hook to retireve all meta data for the registered user:

```
add_action('user_register', 'new_user_func');

// user registration callback function
function new_user_func($userID) {
    $newUser = get_user_meta( $userID );
    $userMeta = array();
    foreach ($newUser as $key => $value) {
        $userMeta[$key] = $value[0];
    }
    //do something with $userMeta...
}
```

var_dump($userMeta) after submit doesn't give me the extra fields value though.. only defaults (first name, last name etc)

Anyone know what might be the case?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try getting the values with:

```
$meta = get_the_author_meta($meta_key, $user_id);
```

Perhaps the meta values you add yourself isn't supported by get_user_meta() .

If this don't work either, perhaps you need to look on how you went about creating the new meta fields. Theres a pretty decent tutorial on how to do it here:
http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/09/10/adding-and-using-custom-user-profile-fields

Comment: get_the_author_meta($meta_key, $user_id) returns a an empty string :/

Comment: i have another hook for profile update so when i edit a user in dashboard it retrieves the extra meta values. i am using ProfileBuilder Pro to add those extra fields.

Answer (score 0):

Read de Codex entry for user_register [action](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register), it says:
Not all user metadata has been stored in the database when this action is triggered.